# SoftEther with Radius authentication

Tags: authentication, ldap, radius

I want to use LDAP authentication for softether. We don't have any direct configarations for that. I google it. Some body said that instead we can use radius authentication for Softether and we can connect radius to LDAP. I tried it. I had done with radius to LDAP connections.

But now want to use radius authentication for softether but Im not getting clues to configure it. Can anybody help to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you basically want to use a radius server to authenticate users on softether. Correct?

If this is the case, then this is an easy one: 
- Add a new user to softether. The user name should be: "*"  without the double quotations
- Set the authentication type of this user to freeradius and enter your server crednetials
- Because the username is a wildcard, any user trying to connect will be forwarded to freeradius for authentication

Hope this helps

Comment: Is there any possibility to use LDAP authentication without adding users to softeither?

Comment: Yes. Since softether is using radius for authentication. You can then use ldap authentication under radius

Comment: So when I use *** user still can check all users which are authenticated from Radius details how much bandwidth consumed? or it will show only one user?